# Der Unterschied zwischen "festsetzen", "festlegen" and "feststellen"

Tags: verb

These three verbs seem to mean pretty much the same thing (to set, or to determine, establish). I would like to know the precise difference between these verbs with examples if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not exactly the same.

## feststellen

This verb concerns observations. It may refer to pure observations (A) or a summary of observations (B).

> (A) Wenn man Wasser auf 100 °C erhitzt, wird man *feststellen*, dass es zu Sieden beginnt.
> (B) Nach ausführlicher Diskussion hat der das Gericht die Schuld des Angeklagten *festgestellt*.

## festlegen

This verb concerns definitions and norms.

> Wir *legen fest*, dass du unser Anführer bist.
> Die Kleiderordnung der Feier ist auf förmlich *festgelegt* worden.

## festsetzen

Apart from a meaning synonymous to `festnehmen`, this is rather synonymous to `festlegen`. One can see a difference to it in the ultimaticy of it, `festsetzen` being rather ultimate while `festlegen` being rather intermediary or changeable.

> Das Kilogramm ist *festgesetzt* als die Masse von einem konkreten Körper, der in Paris liegt.

But this difference is often ignored.

Comment: Both answers are amazing  but I opted fpr this answer as 4 people have already  voted for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Festsetzen** is homonymous for "to arrest somebody" (*jemanden festsetzen*), "to determine" (*etwas festsetzen*), and "to settle down" (*sich festsetzen*), the last one both practical and metaphorical. To my experience, in the meaning of "to determine" it is preferably used in an official or legal context:

> Als nächsten Tagungstermin setzte das Gericht den 2. Mai fest.

Apart from that you would rather use "festlegen". *Festsetzen* is more often used in passive form or as an attribute, e.g. "nach festgesetzten Regeln" (following established rules):

> Als nächster Tagungstermin wurde vom Gericht der 2. Mai festgesetzt.

*festsetzen* in the meaning of "to arrest" is mainly used in a historic or a context outside of civil law:

> Die Rebellen wurden in einem Armeestützpunkt festgesetzt, *but* Die Diebe wurden von der Polizei in Haft genommen.

As opposed to "verhaften" or "gefangennehmen" *festsetzen* explicitly implies both the process of putting and keeping behind bars.

**Festlegen** = to set, to direct, to impose sth. (*etwas festlegen*), to commit oneself to sth. (*sich festlegen auf etwas*):

> Als Bedingung für die Aufnahme wurde festgelegt, dass...
>
> Er hatte sich auf ein rosa Auto festgelegt und war nicht mehr von dieser Farbe abzubringen.

**Feststellen** = to find (out), to establish a fact, or to state.

> Ich stellte fest (*found*), dass das Grundstück viel kleiner war als in der Anzeige angegeben. Daraufhin stellte ich dem Verkäufer gegenüber fest (*stated*), dass ich nicht mehr am Kauf interessiert sei.